# Automation Tool for Siebel Open UI : UFT or Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, hp-uft, siebel

I wanted to know if anybody has automated Siebel OpenUI ( Seiebel 8.1.1.14). If yes which is the tool used and the challenges faced.? Your feedback will help me.

Answer (score 2):

I use both UFT & WebDriver. Both have its own pros & cons.
I have automated Siebel application using UFT in the past.

**UFT**

Pros:

- Has siebel add-in.
- Learning UFT is easy.
- Record & Playback
- We can come up with a decent framework & test script easily.

Cons:

- Commercial tool.
- Works only in windows. (UFT 12 can be used to test safari as well. But it has some limitations)
- Supports IE. other browsers we need to apply patches from HP whenever they release. You might not be able to test latest browsers.
- UFT uses VBScript (even in 2015)

**WebDriver:**

Pros:

- FREE & Open Source
- OS independent.
- Supports almost all browsers.

Cons:

- Learning is not easy as UFT & Difficult to find testers with good programming knowledge.
- It might take time to come up with a framework and create a robust test script.